# maxItemsInObjectGraph - Default Behavior on Operations

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I've followed the 1 billion suggested solutions and have added the maxItemsInObjectGraph behavior to the client endpoint and the server service behavior, but I'm still getting the error that I have exceeded the default limit of 65K.

I noticed when debugging that the Operations have a `System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior` behavior already that is set to the default of 65K.

Why and where is this being set? I have reproduced this with a simple WCF service example and I still see that default behaviour on the Operations.

Comment: Have you set the reader quotas on the service behavior

Comment: I set the readerquotas on the bindings, but it didn't help

Comment: Was it on both client and server side that you set or just on the server. They need to be set on both ends.

Comment: This isn't even what the question is - where do the OperationBehaviors get their value from?

Comment: The operationBehaviours have a default value. If you specify an serviceBehavior or endpointBehavior the default values are overridden with the values you have specified. It would be easy if you could post your configuration file to find the issue